# Slick carousel loads the wrong width on initialization

Tags: slider, carousel, slick.js

On page load, for the first second of so, the first slide only takes up half of the screen before correcting itself. It is causing an unpleasant/snappy load experience. If I monitor the elements code via inspect I can see the inline width get updated about a second into page load. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: it helps if you give it some default css for it to show the intended view until slick loads and takes over the design.
Also, it helps to giving max-height and overflow hidden to the container to avoid overflowing content in the first few seconds

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem
solution is start from prev slide **(initialSlide: ...)** and call **slick('slickNext')**