# Slick slider gets wrong width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

My slick slider gets wrong width when initialized and when I change screen resolutions.

My js:

```
$('.slider').slick({
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    initialSlide: 1,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2
        }
    }, {
        breakpoint: 650,
        settings: {
            initialSlide: 2,
            slidesToShow: 1
        }
    }]
});
```

My css:

```
.sub-slider {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex; 
    flex-flow: column;

    .slider {
        display: flex;   
        flex-flow: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-width:500px;

        .sub-box {
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 45px;
            cursor:pointer;

            .title {
                color: #6deca0;
                font-family: "AmsiProNarw", sans-serif;
                font-size: 48px;
                font-style: italic;
                font-weight: 800;
            }
            .price {
                color: #393939;
                font-family: "AmsiProNarw", sans-serif;
                font-size: 18px;
                font-style: italic;
                font-weight: 800;
            }
            .sub-slider-btn {
                margin: 60px 20px;
                border-color: #eaeaea!important;
                background-color: #fdfdfd!important;
                color: #686868!important;
            }
        }

        .sub-box:hover { 
            transition: border .2s;            
            border-bottom: 14px solid #6deca0;
            .sub-slider-btn{
                border-color: #6deca0!important;
                background-color: rgba(108,235,159,.2)!important;
                color: #393939!important;
            }
        }
    }

    .sub-slider-confirmation-btn-wrp { 
        align-self: center;
        display: none;
        .sub-slider-confirmation-btn {
            cursor:pointer;
            $margin: 20px;
            $height: 45px;
            height: $height;
            width: 80px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 8px;
            margin: $margin $margin $margin $margin;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: $height;  
            font-weight: 800;
        }
    }

}
```

This is how it is loaded, even though I have specified `slidesToShow: 3`.

[image: slider error]

Then when I change to resposive it looks like this:
[image]

I am not sure how to fix this. I have read through these, with no fix:

[Slick slider wrong width on initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989655/slick-slider-wrong-width-on-initialization)

[Slick carousel loads the wrong width on initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944421/slick-carousel-loads-the-wrong-width-on-initialization)

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/790

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1180

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2167

edit:

I made a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/simeydotme/fmo50w7n/

It seems to work in the fiddle, but not on my site. Maybe I inherit some bad css? But I've been trying to debug this for 5h now. And I cant find any solution..

Comment: try to change width the reload page

Comment: _“My css: ...”_ - slick comes with its own styesheet that applies the basic styling needed for it to work. Now when I see you overwriting properties for basic classes the slider uses, then I would first of all question if you have not messed this up yourself by adding those.

Comment: There are some defined sizes for its `css` to work. If you are just resizing the browser with browser maximize button or resize tool, then it might not work as expected until the defined points are reached. I would suggest you to use the emulator to check the responsiveness or use a real time device to verify the same..

Answer (score 36):

I also encountered the same issue - slider track width too large upwards of 30,000px wide.  After reading Spencer Rysman's answer, I reviewed my markup and realized that I had applied a `row` class to the div wrapping my slider and since I'm using bootstrap 4 the default `display:flex` property used with the row class was causing unexpected output with the slide elements.

Adding a col within the wrapping row div fixed the issue for me.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
       ../slider markup
    </div>
</div>
```

Although, this may not be directly related to the op's issue, I thought I'd post as other users may encounter a similar problem as I did and find this thread.

Comment: For ``bulma`` you can use ``<div class="column is-12">``

Comment: I noticed that a wrapper with `display: grid` can also create this trouble in Safari. In my case, changing `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr` to `grid-template-columns: 50% 50%` fixed the problem. It looks like Safari needs a more specific width.

Comment: Add `width: 100%` if you're not using bootstrap.

Comment: Not only in Safari. There's an issue with "fr" units. Changing to anything else solves the problem. Thank you @RyanBurney

Answer (score 11):

## Short Answer:

Make sure that your slick slider is inside of a container which is set as `display: block`

Comment: Added the slick slider into a dialog, had width of 0. After I set min width, I noticed that if I slide, the slider rearranges on each slide and finally reaches the point I'm after. Anyway, adding display: block to the dialog fixed it. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem only on screens <768px with bootstrap4, slick (and owlCarousel) set width more then 10000px to there container. The issue was that's the bootstrap container (.container) does't have a width property <768px, set it to 100% resolve the problem.

Comment: Same, seems like slick just doesn't like being inside of a flex container without a specific width and will grow to infinity. Setting a width: 100% on the top level `.container` fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue and was also dealing with some inherited bad css from stylesheets that I did not author. In my case I found 2 problems:

1. body had a declaration of display: table
2. .page (a page wrapper) had display: inline-block

So I would check to make sure that the slick slider is not nested inside of any element that is displayed as table or inline-block

Comment: A wrapper element with ``display: flex`` could also cause the problem.

Comment: I also had the same issue. Inherited a site that used display:table; and display:table-cell; Changing them to block and inline-block solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

We can't always remove all container's `display: flex` and recode all CSS in page just to make a library work.

In my experience I found that the problem appears after this line:

```
_.$slideTrack.width(Math.ceil((_.slideWidth * _.$slideTrack.children('.slick-slide').length)));
```

in version 1.8.1, where the library sets `.slick-track`'s width it seems that **any** flex container (**any**, not the direct container) will generate the issue.

I fixed forcing (and updating on window resize event) a fixed width to the slider main wrapper, that is the element where you instantiate your slider with `$('#slider-wrap').slick(...)`, using this little Javascript snippet:

```
var $sliderwrap = $('#slider-wrap');

// fix for flex begins here ----
function setW() {
    // use parent width, not always the right way
    // change it if your $sliderwrap parent width 
    // does not match your $sliderwrap width
    $sliderwrap.width($sliderwrap.parent().width());
}
setW();
window.addEventListener('resize', setW);
// end fix here ----

// instantiate the slider
$sliderwrap.slick(...);
```

I hope this can help anyone.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue and after attempting the above-mentioned to no avail. I revisited the [docs](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and added this

> variableWidth: true

to the javascript config block.
so your code looks like this

```
$('.slider').slick({
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    initialSlide: 1,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true, <=== change here
    dots: false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2
        }
    }, {
        breakpoint: 650,
        settings: {
            initialSlide: 2,
            slidesToShow: 1
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On initial loading, slick will not take the width, in IOS - in few devides, if the internal content is heavy.

Its fixed for me by adding css **max-width**  to **slick-track**

Check with following:

```
$(".slick-track").css("max-width", $(window).width());
```

Comment: .slick-track {
         max-width: 100%; }

Comment: this code is broken on a small device, not recommended to use. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `display: flex` for the slick containter. It will cause problem on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

main div container must be
`display:block;`

or

`display:grid; grid-template-columns:repeat(4,minmax(0,1fr));`

`minmax(0,1fr)` is the way. Or a defined width (px, em,...). `display:flex;` is problem.

Answer (score 1):

If any block thing works, add to your CSS file:

```
.slick-track {display: flex !important}

.slick-slide {height: auto;}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to have at-least one entire slide always visible on both **Desktop** and **Mobile**. To do this I used the CSS vw property

```
.slick-slide,.slick-slide img {
   max-width:90vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. To me the problem was caused by a (distant) parent of the slick block having the property `display:grid`. Turning it back to `display:block` fixed the problem for me.

So basically Slick shouldn't be even remotely contained in a flex or grid element.